# Why do these results not contradict Green's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals, curl

I have a vector field $\;\underline{v}(x,y) = \left(\dfrac{-y}{x^{2}+4y^{2}}, \dfrac{x}{x^{2}+4y^{2}}\right)$

$\text{curl }\underline{v} = 0$ and thus the vector field is conservative.

I have a surface, $\Omega$, with $\Omega:=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2: x^2+4y^2=4\right\}$.

A parameterisation of the border of $\Omega$, $\partial\Omega$ is $\underline{r}(t) = \big(2\cos(t), \sin(t)\big)$, for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$

The integral $\oint_{\partial\Omega}\underline{v}\cdot d\underline{r} = \pi$

However, by Green's Theorem, $\oint_{\partial\Omega}\underline{v}\cdot d\underline{r} = \iint_{\Omega}\textbf{curl}\,\underline{v}\text{ }dxdy$. Since curl $\underline{v} = 0$, and the curve is closed, $\oint_{\partial\Omega}\underline{v}\cdot d\underline{r} = 0$

Why are these two results not contradictory?

Edit: I think that this might be because $\underline{v}(0,0)$ is undefined, however I am not sure what difference that would make, nor how to formalise why this is not a contradiction.

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong. Review carefully the hypotheses you need in order to conclude that the vector field is conservative if its curl is $0$.

Comment: Is this because the vector field is undefined at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, since the function is not defined at $(0,0)$... it is analogous to having a pole of a holomorphic function in complex analysis.

Comment: Letting $z=x+i2y$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial \Omega}\vec v\cdot \,d\vec \ell&=\frac12 \text{Im}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac1z\,dz\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$Green's Theorem in the plane does not apply since the real and imaginary parts of $\frac1z$ are not continuously differentiable on $|z|\le 2$.  There is a simple pole at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a conservative vector field is one which is the gradient of some scalar function. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, vector fields which have zero curl are only conservative on *domains without holes* (for example, simply connected regions). Since your vector field is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ (which has a hole) it is not conservative.

However, if you already know the vector field is conservative, it's always true that its curl is zero. This follows from the fact that $\nabla\times(\nabla \phi)=0$.

Comment: “Without holes” is fine in $2$ dimensions, but not in higher dimensions. For example, $\Bbb R^3-\{0\}$ has a hole but is still simply connected.

Comment: No, you were right with simple connectivity (in fact, something a bit weaker, having to do with homology/cohomology rather than homotopy). Contractibility is way too strong a requirement. The Poincaré lemma is a statement for all $k$-forms, but here you only need vanishing first deRham cohomology to conclude that a closed $1$-form must be exact.

Comment: Good point, I realized my mistake.